# Set group_concat_max_len permanently (MySQL config)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have MySQL installed on an Ubuntu machine.

I added this line in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

group_concat_max_len=15360

But there is no effect. Every time I restart mysql, the value is set to 1,024. I have to manually run

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=15360
```

...every time I start up mysql.

Why is my.cnf not working the way I thought it should?
Thank you

Comment: This always happens. It's either 1) wrong file, or  2) something else below had overrwritten it.

Comment: @Pacerier or the directive was added under the wrong group header, as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you have the setting already in my.cnf or my.cfg, and a restart did not bring about the change you expected, you may just have the setting placed in the wrong location.

Make sure the setting is under the [mysqld] group header

```
[mysqld]
group_concat_max_len=15360
```

then you can restart mysqld without worry

BTW @[gbn may be more correct in this instance](https://serverfault.com/a/346876/69271) because you cannot use commas in the numerical settings for my.cnf (+1 for @gbn)

Comment: I spent hours debugging before I realized my group_concat_max_len was reset. Now I will not have to worry about that happening again. Thanks so much. There was no setting for group_concat_max_len by default in my.cnf, so I just added it to the bottom, under [isamchk]. OOPS. Thanks so much!

Comment: It bugs me so much that some settings use dashes and some use underscores in the MySQL config

Answer (score 5):

Use `group_concat_max_len=15360` *without* the thousands separator

See [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)

If this doesn't persist, then you need to identify the *correct* my.cnf or my.cfg used by your installation

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, it was my mistake putting the ',' in my question but not in the my.cnf. Rolando actually was right. I had no idea that the location for group_concat_max_len mattered in my.cnf.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do:
Open MySQL Workbench and select the connection you want to manipulate if you have more than one, then click Server Administration - Advanced - Various, select group_concat_max_len and set your long desired value.
 Remember to restart MySql.
Kind regards,
Ola Balstad.

Comment: That's not setting a permanent setting.

Comment: It is permanent!!! Please check before you comment.

Comment: What is mysql workbench? It sounds like your answer applies only to a particular API for MySQL. That's probably why you're getting downvoted. (I didn't downvote you, by the way)

Comment: MySql Workbench is a useful API tool that comes with the MySQL Community Server when you download it, i.e with the latest version 5.6

Comment: NB!! Do not get discouraged by my rating. This is a quick and good solution to a common problem.